# Update Values in PySimpleGui from external script

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

I am new to PySimpleGui and wonder if the following concept can be applied.
I have to work with two scripts, one related to a GUI and a second one that it is a "Do Something Script".
I am interested in printing the status of an external loop in a window of my GUI Script

The GUIScript that I have coded as an example is the following:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import MainScript

### GUI Script ###
layout = [
    [sg.Text('My text 1 is: '), sg.Text('{}'.format('foo1'), key='-text1-')],
    [sg.Text('My text 2 is: '), sg.Text('{}'.format('foo2'), key='-text2-')],
    [sg.Text('Sweep number: '), sg.Text('{}'.format('0'), key='-SWEEP-')],
    [sg.ProgressBar(max_value=40, orientation='horizontal', size=(50,20), key='-PRO_BAR-')],
    [sg.Button("OK"), sg.Button("Cancel")],
    ]
window =sg.Window("Progress Bar",layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                break
    if event == "OK":
        for s in range(50):
            event, values = window.read(1000)
            if event == 'Cancel':
                break
            window['-PRO_BAR-'].update(s+1)
            window['-text1-'].update('my new text1')
            window['-text2-'].update('my new text2')
            window['-SWEEP-'].update(s)
            window.refresh()
window.close()
```

The previous script works as "what I would like to have". I mean that the `window['-PRO_BAR-'].update(s+1)` and `window['-SWEEP-'].update(s)` update according to the `s` value of its own for-loop.

However, I would like to pick up the variable=`i` from the MainScript (which is the following), and use it back in the GUIScript.

```
##### MainScript ####
SWEEPS = 50
SWEEPS_LEN = list(range(1, SWEEPS+1))
for i in enumerate(SWEEPS_LEN):
    print('sweep: {}'.format(i))
    # Do something
    # Save Data
```

Here, it is obvious that i=0, i=1, i=2.... I want to use these variables (that change in the  loop) them as:
`window['-PRO_BAR-'].update(i+1)` and `window['-SWEEP-'].update(i)`, such as the values update.

The GUIScript would show:
`Sweep: 1`
then i=2, updates and shows
`Sweep: 2`
then updates and...

Thanks.

Comment: it would be better to keep code in function in `MainScript` - so later you can decide when to use it.

Comment: `s` is in lop so it may have different values. If you want to do something with `s` then you should do it inside this loop. But have to no idea what you want to do with this `s`. You should better describe  it.

Comment: @furas I tried to explain it better after editing the post. Basically, I would like to print in my window, values from another script.

Comment: Reroute stdout to a `Multiline` element (or use `Output` element) if you want prints to show up in your GUI.  This would enable any module to output to your window without any linkage between the GUI code and the other parts of your code.

Comment: better modify your code in `MainScript` and use `window['-PRO_BAR-'].update(i+1)` directly inside `for`-loop. And if you want to update progressbar then this function may have to run in separated thread - because code can run two things at the same time.